# iOS Google Maps API - Views and Labels will not Overlay Over the Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have created a Google Map view using the Google Maps SDK for iOS and the map displays fine. Then I added a label on top of the Map. When I run this the label will not show on top of the map. I've tried moving the label to different positions, messing with constraints, but nothing seems to make the label show. I've also tried putting the label in the View instead of it being a child of Map. It still will not show.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.4987309,
            longitude: -77.4700891, zoom: 10)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView
    }
}
```

Here is the storyboard:
[image: Here is the storyboard]

[image]

Comment: instead of `self.view = mapView`, try `self.view.addSubview(mapView)`

Comment: this has no effect, the label is still missing

Comment: Are you sure your autolayout constraints for the label are correct? The orange line at the bottom of the picture indicates that  it will show up differently at runtime

Comment: To test, I've set the constraints for the label to 0,0,0,0 it should show right in the middle. But still it will not show. I also tried setting the constaints to 0 bottom, 0 left, and 0 right, still nothing. I've also created a new view, and set the constraints to 0,0,0,0 with a white background, and still nothing shows up on top of the map.

It's almost like the map is removing any views I add, or the map is just always on top no matter what. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Drag a new view

[image]

into your storyboard and place it under your label like the picture.

[image]

Then CTRL+drag from the "Map View" to the "View" and shift+click the following options and click "add constraints"

[image]

This is simply setting the simple autolayout constraints. CTRL+drag the "Map View" into your view controller's class.

Replace `self.view = mapView`, with `self.theMapView.addSubview(mapView)`.

(where theMapView is the "Map View" in the storyboard)

Now, instead of your actual main view adding the map as a view, you're just creating a subview that does the same, and you have full control of what goes on top of what!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation and here is how I solved it.

- In your storyboard you have a view named 'Map'
- You created the following camera :

  ```
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.4987309,
  longitude: -77.4700891, zoom: 10)
  ```
- Control drag the 'Map' View onto your view controller and name it whatever, such as mapView
- `self.mapView.camera = camera
   self.mapView.bringSubview(toFront: yourLabelToBePlacedOnTop)`